# The middle of obscuring and appreciating positive psychology

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, psychology

I am examining characters who have ideologies or outlooks that lead or obscure appreciation of the attributes of positive psychology. Within the spectrum of both, what do you call the middle person who neither obscures nor appreciates the psychology?

**Sample Sentence:**

> Within the spectrum of modern day psychology, it is possible to lie mid-way in the continuum, _______ the idea.

Comment: They could be apathetic, silent or balanced, etc. Please include a sample sentence that clarifies your intended idea by an example. E.g. for *silent* - "He says nothing about psychology, so as a/an ____ person, he sort of fits between obscuring and appreciating it." Also have a look at these posts: [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), [2](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/7709/142322).

Comment: Sample Sentence: Within the spectrum of modern day psychology, it is possible to lie mid-way in the continuum, _______ the idea.

Comment: That sample sentence looks like you're asking for a verb. Is that the case? By the way, it's better to edit the question (click the word "edit" under your question) to insert the sample sentence because it improves the question itself, and also because unlike questions, comments may be deleted with little or no warning to us.

Comment: Pleae see also [cogsci.se] Good Luck.

Comment: "...,remaining neutral to the idea " /  "....giving the idea a pass"  / ".....paying no heed to the idea" /

Comment: I'd call him "the person in the muddle".

Comment: Note that it's unclear in what sense you're using the word "appreciate".

Comment: As @HotLicks pointed out, you are delineating a strange axis. *Obscuring* suggests an unawareness of, while *appreciating* suggests attaching positive value to. They don't form a continuum in my mind. The continuums that come to mind are aware/ unaware, relevant/irrelevant and positive/negative valuation.

Answer (score 1):

The first word that comes to my mind is *independent.* As I understand the context, this works perfectly. Obviously, you need to add 'of' if you are using this, and you may also choose to include the word 'remaining.' In context:

...*independent on* the idea.

or

...*remaining independent of* the idea.

My personal solution as an editor would be to rephrase and use something like this:

"It is possible within the spectrum of modern day psychology to lie mid-way in the continuum, *maintaining a position of neutrality on* the idea."

For the sake of brevity, I might also remove 'on the idea' entirely, and simply end the sentence with *maintaining a position of neutrality,* IF the context is explained thoroughly enough to omit this.

Comment: And perhaps also worth adding a more concise option: "midway on the continuum, neutral to / neutral on the idea."

Answer (score 0):

You may use the term ***oblivious to***.

[From M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivious):

> **oblivious** : not conscious or aware of someone or something
>
> She rested now, frankly and fairly, in the shelter of his arms, and
>   both were *oblivious to* the gale that rushed past them in quicker and
>   stronger blasts. —Jack London, Burning Daylight, 1910
>
> the out-of-state motorist claimed to be *oblivious* of the local speed
>   limit, even though the signs must have been hard to miss

Your example:

Within the spectrum of modern day psychology, it is possible to lie mid-way in the continuum, *oblivious to* the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could say **having a [dispassionate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dispassionate) view of** the idea. This implies that they are knowledgeable about the idea but are not committed in either direction. It is similar to **being [open-minded](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/open-minded)** about it but different in that open-mindedness carries the implication of a somewhat greater willingness, perhaps even eagerness, to be convinced one way or another.